# How to number Duplicate rows in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, greatest-n-per-group, row-number

I'm trying to figure out the best/easiest way to number duplicate rows accordingly.I have a set of data that I am uploading to the database table. I have uploaded it, and auto incremented it, now I want to generate the order_id in the fashion shown in my question. For example

```
    ----ID-------NAME-----------ORDER_ID----------
        1        Bob Smith        1
        2        Steve Jones      2
        3        Bob Smith        1
        4        Billy Guy        3
        5        Steve Jones      2
    ----------------------------------------------
```

I was thinking I could use a statement such as `select NAME from table where name= duplicate_name` but I can't seem to figure out how I would realistically go about that, much less then enter the appropriate `ORDER_ID` afterwards. Is there an easy way to do this ?

Comment: In modern RDBMS supporting [window functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29#Window_function), this is very simple: `SELECT name, dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS order_id
FROM   tbl`. Sadly, MySQL is not among those.

Comment: Well that sucks. Is there a way to do his in MySQL or am I out of luck ?

Comment: There is always a way, just more complicated ...

Comment: lol thats what I figured. I guess it's better to go complicated then not at all. suggestions?

Comment: I am guessing you build on a table with `(id, name)` and want to generate `order_id` additionally as displayed. Your question might be more clear about that.

Comment: I have a set of data that I am uploading to the database table. I have uploaded it, and auto incremented it, now I want to generate the `order_id` in the fashion shown in my question. Hope that clears up any confusion.

Comment: Yes. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26600464/edit) your question to make it clear. Shouldn't be hidden in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT 
  A.ID, 
  A.NAME, 
  (SELECT TOP 1 T.ID 
    FROM table AS T 
    WHERE T.NAME = A.NAME 
    ORDER BY T.ID) AS ORDER_ID 

  FROM table AS A
```

If your database engine does not support the TOP keyword, but does support the LIMIT keyword, you may be able to do this:

```
SELECT 
      A.ID, 
      A.NAME, 
      (SELECT T.ID 
        FROM table AS T 
        WHERE T.NAME = A.NAME 
        ORDER BY T.ID
        LIMIT 1) AS ORDER_ID 

      FROM table AS A
```

Comment: had to take out TOP because it would not work with mysql. Tried replacing it with LIMIT but, it didn't like that either. When I try running it without `TOP 1`, it gives me an error saying `error code 1242 subquery returns more than 1 row`

Comment: I'm not sure about MySQL, but this is how I would use limit in PostGres. MySQL may be similar..Someone else may know this here. Also, The TOP/LIMIT 1 is essential in this query because you are selecting a single value from the subquery.

SELECT 
  A.ID, 
  A.NAME, 
  (SELECT T.ID 
    FROM table AS T 
    WHERE T.NAME = A.NAME 
    ORDER BY T.ID LIMIT 1) AS ORDER_ID 

  FROM table AS A

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.*, t1.order_id
FROM  (
   SELECT name, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS order_id
   FROM  (
      SELECT name, min(id) AS min_id
      FROM   tbl
      GROUP  BY name
      ) t0
   ,  (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
   ORDER  BY min_id
   ) t1
JOIN tbl t USING (name);
```

1. In the subquery `t0` aggregate all names and compute the minimum `id` per name. You seem to want to number names after first appearance according to `id`. This is subtly different from just adding `dense_rank()` like I commented.
2. [Simulating the basic window function `row_number()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1895127/939860), tag a running number to each name according to this order in `t1`.
3. Join back to the base table.